# How to resolve DEP6957 error when running Windows Universal Samples?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to run one of the samples from the Windows Universal Samples package:

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

I have properly unzipped all of the files required and changed the platform target to x86 from ARM.

*However I still get this error:*

**DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '127.0.0.1' using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings. COMException - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007274D) [0x8007274D]**

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Which sample you have tested?

Comment: And have you tried to modify the platform to x64?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '127.0.0.1'

I have research some similar issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/issues/80), And the provided solution is modify the debug platform from `Arm` to others. I found you have used x86 platform, please try to test with x64 and clean and rebuild your solution.

> Are you trying to run against an ARM desktop device? If not this is just an obnoxious quirk of Visual Studio where it defaults to the ARM configuration when you first load the solution. You need to choose x64 from the platform target dropdown.